# Fatal Error When Trying To Save Core Data Objects Via Relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am adding a newly created user exercise to an existing user routine via a save command. To explain the code below, I set the objectcontext, then is the exercise is new (userExercise is nil) I execute a new save block.

I then check if this new exercise is being added to an existing routine (associatedRoutineToAddTo is a string routine name from the previous VC).

This is where the issue is. I attempt to get the UserRoutine object that it needs to be added to, using a predicate based on the routines name from the string i passed from the previous VC. then i attempt to add the exercise to the routine. This causes the crash.

The rest of the code isnt too relevant as it works fine in terms of saving an edit or new exercise with no parent routine, its just this one part.

Here is what I am trying:

```
func getMainContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

func createExercise() {
    print("SAVE EXERCISE PRESSED")
    let managedObjectContext = getMainContext()

    if userExercise == nil {
        print("SAVING THE NEW EXERCISE")
        let newUserExercise = UserExercise(context: self.managedObjectContext!)
        newUserExercise.name = userExerciseName.text
        newUserExercise.sets = Int64(userSetsCount)
        newUserExercise.reps = Int64(userRepsCount)
        newUserExercise.weight = Double(self.userExerciseWeight.text!)!
        newUserExercise.dateCreated = NSDate()

        if self.associatedRoutineToAddTo != nil {

            let existingUserRoutine = UserRoutine(context: managedObjectContext)
            let request: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine.name == %@", self.associatedRoutineToAddTo!)
            existingUserRoutine.addToUserexercises(newUserExercise)

            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }

        } else if self.associatedRoutineToAddTo == nil {
            print("THIS IS A FRESH EXERCISE WITHOUT A PARENT ROUTINE")
        }
    }
```

The error reads:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'usersroutine' between objects in different contexts (source = <UserExercise: 0x618000280e60>
```

edit: revised my fetch code for review:

```
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserRoutine> = UserRoutine.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine.name == %@", self.associatedRoutineToAddTo!)

        do {
            existingUserRoutine = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! UserRoutine
            print("Routine Below Fetched")
            print(existingUserRoutine)
        } catch {
            print("Fetch Failed")
        }

        existingUserRoutine.addToUserexercises(newUserExercise)
```

Comment: Please show the crash log and the error that is printed out

Comment: I have updated the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the object here:

`let newUserExercise = UserExercise(context: self.managedObjectContext!)`

And fetch the related object here:

`let existingUserRoutine = UserRoutine(context: managedObjectContext)`

You've created a local variable called `managedObjectContext` here:

`let managedObjectContext = getMainContext()`

And your error states:

> attempt to establish a relationship 'usersroutine' between objects in different contexts

Therefore, your property `managedObjectContext` is not the same as that returned by `getMainContext()`

In addition to all that, you're creating a brand new `UserRoutine`, and assigning it to a value called `existingRoutine`, then creating a fetch request that you don't do anything with, which suggests you're a little confused about what is supposed to be happening here.

Comment: I have removed the self so that both contexts are managedObjectContext and that resolves the crash, however as you said it seems to just create a new routine. I am a little confused as Im not experienced in core data. how would i approach successfully adding the exercise to the routine and saving that existing routine rather than a new routine? Appreciate the advice

Comment: Instead of creating a new routine, execute the fetch request and use the result

Comment: I added amended code to the bottom of my OP, i know its not 100% as i have errors but is that logic correct? request the user routines based on the predicate of the existing routines name then set that result as the existing routine and add the user exercise to the routine?

Comment: Almost, you need to execute the request (see NSManagedObjectContext execute method)

Comment: ive made a few more edits is this further from where i need to be or closer? only issue im working on is how to get the UserRoutine object from the fetch controller

Comment: You don't need a fetched results controller. Just use the contexts execute method with the fetch request. Honestly it sounds like you need to read some basic core data material, there are plenty of guides out there.

Comment: Thanks i have rolled it back to what i had before, you are correct but i cant find what i need googling 'contexts execute method'

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1948986-fetch sorry, they renamed it for swift 3 :)

Comment: Thanks i added what i believed to be what i needed to add but im getting crashing and it isnt working, i revised the OP with the execute if you can let me know if im getting it wrong? Im getting UserRoutine as an array and so it wont let me use .addToUserexercises as it isnt an managedobject

Comment: fetch returns an _array_ of results, use `managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first` to get the first result.

Comment: Brilliant i spent ages trying to figure how to pull the first object form the array. it all works now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WHen you make UserExcercise you are referencing a context saved on your VC:

```
    let newUserExercise = UserExercise(context: self.managedObjectContext!)
```

Then

```
        let existingUserRoutine = UserRoutine(context: managedObjectContext)
```

The `getMainContext()` acquire context here?